# How to investigate what has been learnt in CNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification

My `CNN` was trained using close-up images of dogs. For testing, we input an image with a dog next to its owner and it was classified as a dog. How is that possible? 
Isn't this image a different vector?

Comment: Please add more information what are you trying to do.
E.g. Are you doing image classification or semantic segmentation?

Comment: I'm doing image classification using fastai module (cnn built upon resnet34 architecture)

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous paper about tracking what a CNN network has learnt. You can visualise to see which parts are more engaged in the classification using *DeConvNet*. In this paper, it was officially observed that first layers attempt to find simple lines and edges while deeper layers try to put the previous things together to make abstract concepts, like mouth, eye and such meaningful things. As an example take a look at the following image:

[image]

I guess there are implementations of this paper that you can replace your pre-trained model with the one already exists and see what exactly is learnt by your network.

> Isn't this image a different vector?

They are different vectors. ML and DL models are for generalisation which means they should be good at test time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [innvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) toolkit to heatmap the input pixels relevant for the decision.

Concerning your question: CNNs are trained to be translate and scale invariant, so it is not surprising it fires for an image containing a dog.